# Can Raspberry Pi be used for LVDS image signal reconstruction

Tags: fpga, raspberry-pi, signal-processing, lvds, image-sensor

I have a NOIP3SN5000A image sensor manufactured by Onsemi with a LVDS output. I would like to reconstruct the output signals into images by a Raspberry Pi 4B, can it work?

I have seen a lot of articles reconstructing LVDS signals by FPGA, I wonder if Raspberry Pi can do the same thing.

Or, do anyone use NOIP1SN5000A image sensor before? Any development advice?

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: What’s the motivation for using this sensor in particular? As mentioned below it will be quite a project to interface this sensor to a pi, or any other off the shelf sbc I’ve encountered. Perhaps a friendlier image sensor is in order?

Answer (score 1):

There's a camera port but no LVDS hardware, so you'd need to design something to convert the signals.

Typically in this case you'd buy a camera module that supports something like USB. In that case the vendor is handling the hard parts for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are right, I am looking for a camera module which supports USB or CSI interface now. The camera is supposed to be explosed on a red laser so I want it to perform well on 800nm wavelength as well as a high dynamic range, any recommendation?